# Multiple models creation and updation under one transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions

I wanted to know if its possible in rails to do multiple updates and creations under one transaction.

I wanted to create a no. of `Products` from any array. But for each product i also need to create `Company` and `Category` for it.

So the idea is like this

```
-- Start a transaction
//create a company
//create a category
while product_list
{
   //create a product with company and category created above
}
-- end a transcation
```

So if any of the creation fails i want the earlier updation/creations to rollback.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    # create a company
    # create a category
    while product_list
    {
      # create a product with company and category created above
    }
  end
rescue => e
  # something went wrong, transaction rolled back
end
```

Comment: By the way what command we use for rollbacking the transaction?

Comment: raise ActiveRecord::Rollback in a transaction will cause a rollback. (This exception won't propagate beyond the transaction block so you don't need to catch it)